# Codeigniter redirect url with hashtag is not working

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to redirect the url with hashtag in Codeigniter3. There is no error but its not redirect with hashtag. Please help me to fix it.

```
http://localhost:8888/CodeIgniter/index/aboutus#aboutusredirect
```

Controller.

```
public function aboutus()
{ 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim'); 
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
     {  
       $this->load->view('include/header.php');
       $this->load->view('about');
       $this->load->view('include/footer.php');
     }
     else
     {
       $this->load->view('profilecreate');
     }
}
```

Comment: In the else part you can use codeigniter redirect function

Comment: why u need this? `#aboutusredirect`

Comment: @RajkumarR If I use redirect function then the error message is not showing under the input fields. 
If I use the above code then its working error messages also displaying under each input field. But when its going back to the form. Its going top of the form. Actually submit form is in bottom of that page. Thatswhy im using #tag to take top in the viewer side.

Comment: @devpro Actually the submit form is bottom of the page. When the validation check and it return to top of this page. But submit form is in bottom. I have to take that to top. Thatswhy im using #tag.

Comment: @devpro No. But I solved this issue by using "set_flashdata" in codeigniter

Answer (score 1):

Inside the if condition change

`$this->load->view('include/header.php');
$this->load->view('about');
$this->load->view('include/footer.php');`

use redirect function like below:

> redirect('index/aboutus#aboutusredirect');

Answer (score 0):

you can use required_once() function in 'about' view and then use redirect() for go another page.
you change about view like this :

```
required_once('include/header.php')
//html tag in about view
required_once('include/footer.php')
```

and then you're code must be like this :

```
public function aboutus()
{ 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('name', 'Name', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim'); 
$this->form_validation->set_rules('subject', 'Subject', 'required');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('message', 'Message', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
 {  
   $this->load->view('about');
 }
 else
 {
   $this->load->view('profilecreate');
 }
}
```